# Meteor Accounts.onLogin infinite loop

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

In the Meteor forums I read that it is suggested to put `Meteor.logoutOtherClients` inside `Accounts.onLogin()`. Although this works, there is a problem to it, and that is the `Accounts.onLogin()` gets called multiple times when there are multiple TABS (not browsers) opened. Is this the expected output?

Here is my code below:

```
Accounts.onLogin(() => {
  console.log('onLogin called')
  Meteor.logoutOtherClients((error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(`error: ${error.error}`)
    }
  })

  // Some Meteor Method calls here
  alert('Welcome User!')
})
```

Another problem is that I got method calls in the same `Accounts.onLogin()` block and it gets called every time.

```
meteor@1.4.2.6
accounts-base@1.2.17
```

#### Question

1. How should I prevent this infinite calls from happening?
2. If I can't prevent this, where should I dispatch method calls when user logs in? Because obviously if I put it inside this code block it causes the dispatches to get called infinitely and that `alert` gets fired infinitely.

You can also see the details reported here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8669

Comment: What's your actual question? Do you want to avoid logging out other tabs on the same system?

Comment: Hi @MichelFloyd I just updated my question. Does that help identify my problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why this would infinite loop. Is some tab being logged-in then out then in again indefinitely?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I'm not sure myself, it seems to be like that. I already reported this on Meteor. You can see it there and the replication including the minimum setup to tepilicate the bug. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8669

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a confirmed bug [#8669](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8669). So my workaround is I created a manual token for the user instead of using the default from `accounts-base`. I also handled the checking manually so basically getting rid of "magic" Meteor offers.